# find how many gotos are in a c++ project

Tags: c++, regex, grep, goto

I am trying to see how many `goto` instructions are inside a c++ project. Now I am using a simple matching with `grep` searching for `"goto "`:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir "third_party" --include "*.cpp" --include "*.h" --include "*.C" --include "*.cxx" --include "*.hcc" --include "*.c" --include "*.cc" "goto " .
```

I get a lot of fake positive, in particular inside comments:

```
// Perform stack overflow check if this goto needs it before jumping.
```

or inside literals:

```
stream->Add(" goto (");
```

what is the easiest way to avoid them? I don't need a perfect solution.

Comment: Do you specifically need the easiest way? Or would *any* way that provides a correct answer be sufficient?

Comment: Are all instances of `goto` on a single line?  If so, a simple regex that looks for lines like `^\s*goto\s.*` should work.

Comment: Replace all 'goto' strings with 'gotozzz', compile and count the number of compilation errors.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic what about `std::gotozzz`?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: compile some huge projects can take hours, I need something faster

Comment: It might be a very inefficient hack, but if you "#define goto error" somewhere global (project settings maybe) you should get one compiler error for every goto in your project. Comments and string literals will be wrong, but still compile.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: you are missing `if (current == end) goto parsing_done;`

Comment: @wiso, well, you said easiest, not fastest :) yes, I am aware that it might take time

Comment: @wiso: If you want exact then compilation or some analysis tools. If you want an estimate Stephen Burnaps or Rob suggestion seems ok.

Comment: @wiso If gotos aren't on a single like, you'd need a regex that knew how to handle comment markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regular expression to: `'goto[ \t]+[_A-Za-z0-9]+[ \t]*;'` This will search for the word goto, its target label and a semicolon all on the same line.

Comment: And will not match tab delimited labels.

Comment: Yeah, my first edit was `goto\s+\w+\s*;`, but egrep doesn't take `\s`. Fixed.

Comment: .. and the whole approach won't find any `goto` statement that exceeds 1 line ...

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a static analysis tool like e.g. [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) for doing this. Handling all the possible situations only using regex might turn out not to be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `awk` or another tool that can use more than one regular expression or write a script.

The more difficult cases are:

```
/*****
 * Goto system failure if this point is reached.
 */
```

Meaning anything inside C-style comments.